# How can I copy a data inserted from table to be inserted in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables

```
transaction_tbl
order_tbl
```

I inserted data in `transaction_tbl` with a primary key autoincrement `transaction_no`.

Now, I need to insert data in `order_tbl` with columns

```
orderitem_no(AI, PK), 
transaction_no, 
product_sku, 
quantity
```

How can I sync the `transaction_no` from `transaction` table in one process?

I just assign data to variables then:

My current code is

```
$sql0 = "INSERT INTO transaction_tbl (transaction_no, transaction_date, customer_name) VALUE ('', now(), '$customer_name');";

$x=0;
while ($x!=5){
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO order_tbl
                    (orderitem_no, transaction_no, product_sku, quantity) 
            VALUE ('', '', '$product_sku', '$quantity');";
$x=$x+1;
}
```

Nothing next. Sorry, Im super lost.

Im planning to run ths sql's in one process.

transaction_no in transaction_tbl is auto increment.

I have fk_trans_no in order_tbl.

And then I totally lost. orderitem_no is auto increment but what will I do to the transaction_no?

Comment: Show us the code you have currently

Comment: $sql1 = "INSERT INTO transaction_tbl VALUE ('', $customer_name);";

Comment: No the relevant PHP code around that single SQL statement. And edit it into your question

Comment: Edited. Sorry, Im totally new here.

Comment: Thats ok, we all were once

Comment: So do you create a transaction before you do this? Or do you fetch the transaction?

Comment: We need to see more of your PHP code, remember we are not looking over your shoulder. We only know what you tell us about what you are doing

Comment: Its quite unorganised sorry but I'll do it. Sorry

Comment: Edited thats just it. Im not trying to hide my codes. Its just that I have in my laptop and I have problem with its connection to the internet. Sorry

Comment: Ok, thats 2 SQL statements in strings. Look up `lastInserId()` in the PHP Manual under PDO

Comment: I like that the first related question is [**How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), you should read that up!! And if this is really about CakePHP, then please clarify how so - thanks!